If $f:\mathbb{R}-\{-1,K\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}-\{\alpha,\beta\}$ is a function given by $f(x)=\dfrac{(2x-1)(2x^2-4 px+p^3)}{(x+1)(x^2-p^2x+p^2)}$

If $f:\mathbb{R}-\{-1,K\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}-\{\alpha,\beta\}$ is a bijective function defined by $f(x)=\dfrac{(2x-1)(2x^2-4
px+p^3)}{(x+1)(x^2-p^2x+p^2)}$, where $p\geq 0$, then which if the following is/are true?
(a) If $K\in(-1,1)$ then $\alpha+\beta=2$
(b) If $K\in(-1,1)$ then $\alpha+\beta=6$
(c) If $K\in(1,3)$ then $\alpha+\beta=2$
(d) If $K\in(1,3)$ then $\alpha+\beta=6$

My Approach:
Since $-1,K$ are not in domain of $f(x)$. Hence denominator of $f(x)$ will be zero two values of $x$.
Case $1$: It may be possible that $x^2-p^2x+p^2$ may have factor $(x+1)$ in that case $x^2-p^2x+p^2=(x+1)(x-K)$ and denominator will be zero at $x=-1$ and $x=K$.
If $(x+1)$ is factor of $x^2-p^2x+p^2$ then $(-1)^2-p^2(-1)+p^2=0$ hence $2p^2+1=0$ so this is not possible for real $p$.
Case $2$: $x^2-p^2x+p^2$ is perfect square Hence discriminant will be zero.
If I do $D=b^2-4ac=0$ then I get two values of $p$ namely $0,2$
Subcase $1$: If $p=0$ then $f(x)=\dfrac{(2x-1)(2x^2)}{(x+1)(x^2)}$
for $x\neq 0 , x\neq -1$. I get $f(x)=\dfrac{2(2x-1)}{(x+1)}$ Hence range of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}-\{-2,4\}$
Subcase $2$: If $p=2$ then $f(x)=\dfrac{(2x-1)2(x-2)^2}{(x+1)(x-2)^2}$
for $x\neq 2 , x\neq -1$. I get $f(x)=\dfrac{2(2x-1)}{(x+1)}$ Hence range of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}-\{2,4\}$
I am getting option $(a)$ and $(d)$ as answers
My Doubt:
(1) Is my approach correct?
(2) Solution given is as follow and I don't know why did they consider $(x+1)$ a factor of $2x^2-4px+p^3$ and then said $(2x-1)$ is a factor of $x^2-p^2x+p^2$


Yes your approach is correct and the answer should be ad

(1)
I think your approach is correct.
(In the two subcases, you might want to write that $f(x)$ is a bijective function.)

(2)
I think the given solution is wrong since they forgot to consider the case $p=0$.

I don't know why did they consider $(x+1)$ a factor of $2x^2-4px+p^3$ and then said $(2x-1)$ is a factor of $x^2-p^2x+p^2$

It is difficult to guess what they did not write, but maybe they think that if $f(x)$ is a bijective function, then $f(x)$ has to be of the form $\frac{cx+d}{ax+b}$, and that they have the following two cases to consider :

$x+1$ is a factor of $2x^2-4px+p^3$, and $2x-1$ is a factor of $x^2-p^2x+p^2$.

$\dfrac{2x^2-4px+p^3}{x^2-p^2x+p^2}$ is a constant function.


